# nginx прокси для iis

Tags: nginx, proxy, iis

Доброго времени суток.
Есть IIS с кучей сайтов, висят они на 443 и 80 портах. IIS смотрит в интернет и всё работает отлично.

Решил прикрутить *nginx* на отдельной тачке для облегчения участи первого. Для начала решил просто по HTTP провести, но и тут столкнулся с проблемой.

11.12.13.14 - публичный айпи IIS, есть внутренний для БД, но я его пока не использую.

**site.ru.conf**:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;

server_name site.ru;

access_log /var/log/nginx/site_access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/site_error.log;

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host site.ru; # тут пробовал экспериментировать, ничего не поменялось
    proxy_pass http://11.12.13.14/;
}
}
```

**nginx.conf****:**

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  4;

events {
 worker_connections  4096;
}
http {
 include       mime.types;
 include ..
 include ..
 default_type  application/octet-stream;
 sendfile        on;
 keepalive_timeout  65;
 server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  location / {
   root   html;
   index  index.html index.htm;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
   root   html;
  }
 }
}
```

В днс прописал айпи сервера *nginx*. 
Выдаёт ошибку:

> Не удается получить доступ к сайту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в попытке подключиться по внешнему адресу внутри одной сети. Без дополнительных настроек на шлюзе, такая схема неработоспособна. Вот описание причины неработоспособности: https://enginegr.blogspot.ru/2016/09/ip-mikrotik.html

Используйте внутренний IP IIS и всё заработает

Comment: Пробовал без слеша и без set header - ничего не меняется.

Comment: Стоп. У вас nginx и iis в одной сети?

Comment: Без дополнительных настроек на шлюзе, вариант с подключением ко внутреннему ресурсу по внешнему адресу работать не будет. Указывайте внутренний ip IIS

Comment: С внутренним айпи я понял, спасибо. Под дополнительными настройками на шлюзе, что подразумевается не подскажете?

Comment: См ответ. Если ответ помог - прошу пометить его как "Верный"